# List directories not containing certain files?

Tags: bash, shell, testing, wildcard

I used this command to find all the directories containing .mp3 in the current directory, and filtered out only the directory names:

```
find . -iname "*.mp3" | sed -e 's!/[^/]*$!!' -e 's!^\./!!' | sort -u
```

I now want the opposite, but I found it a little harder. I can't just add a '!' to the find command since it'll only exclude .mp3 when printing them not find directories that do not contain .mp3.

I googled this and searched on stackoverflow and unix.stackexchange.com.
I have tried this script so far and it returns this error:

```
#!/bin/bash

find . -type d | while read dir
do
if [[! -f $dir/*.mp3 ]]
then
    echo $dir
fi
done
```

/home/user/bin/try.sh: line 5: [[!: command not found

```
#!/bin/bash

find . -type d | while read dir
do
if [! -f $dir/*.mp3 ]
then
    echo $dir
fi
done
```

/home/user/bin/try.sh: line 5: [!: command not found

```
#!/bin/bash

find . -type d | while read dir
do
if [[! -f "$dir/*.mp3" ]]
then
    echo $dir
fi
done
```

/home/user/bin/try.sh: line 5: [!: command not found

I'm thinking it has to do with multiple arguments for the test command.

Since I'm testing all the directories the variable is going to change, and I use a wildcard for the filenames.

Any help is much appreciated.  Thank You.

Comment: related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/196960/find-directories-that-dont-contain-a-file

Answer (score 3):

```
[ "$(echo $dir/*.mp3)" = "$dir/*.mp3" ]
```

should work.

Or simply add a space between '[' and '!'

A method that is probably significantly faster is

```
if find "$dir" -name '*.mp3' -quit ; then
  : # there are mp3-files in there.
else
  ; # no mp3:s
fi
```

Comment: Adding a space between `[` and `!` would fix the immediate error, but the test would still fail in directories with more than one .mp3 file. The `echo` approach works much better (although it can still fail on a directory that contains a single .mp3 with the exact name `*.mp3`).

Comment: The find solution also scales better if there are multiple extensions that need to be tested.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I made the change with the space, but it still returned the name of the directory even though there was no mp3's inside.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I solved my own answer by using a counter.

I don't know how efficient it is, but it works.  I know it can be made better. Please feel free to critique.

```
find . -type d | while read dir
do
count=`ls -1 "$dir"/*.mp3 2>/dev/null | wc -l`
    if [ $count = 0 ]
    then
        echo $dir
    fi
done
```

This prints all directories not containing MP3s It also shows sub-directories thanks to the find command printing directories recursively.

Answer (score 0):

I ran a script to automatically download cover art for my mp3 collection. It put a file called "cover.jpg" in the directory for each album for which it could retrieve the art.  I needed to check for which albums the script had failed - i.e. which CDs (directories) did not contain a file called cover.jpg. This was my effort:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d | while read dir; do [[ ! -f $dir/cover.jpg ]] && echo "$dir has no cover art"; done
```

The maxdepth 1 stops the find command from descending into a hidden directory which my WD My Cloud NAS server had created for each album and placed a default generic disc image. (This got cleared during the next scan.)

Edit: cd to the MP3 directory and run it from there, or change the . in the command above to the path to point to it.